# Custom GTM Variable for Breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a custom GTM JavaScript variable that will return the value of a specific breadcrumb link in the JSON-LD.

However my the loop I wrote is only returning the first value:

**JavaScript (GTM Variable)**

```
function() { 
    var bcLink = document.getElementsByClassName("bcLink");
    for (i=0; i<bcLink.length; i++) { 
        return bcLink[i].getAttribute("href");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a class="bcLink" href="http://www.site1.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="bcLink" href="http://www.site2.com">Dumpsters</a></li>
    <li><a class="bcLink" href="http://www.site3.com">State</a></li>
    <li><a class="bcLink active" href="http://www.site4.com">City</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Outputed JSON-LD**

```
{"@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"@id":"http://www.site1.com","name":"Dumpsters"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"@id":"http://www.site1.com","name":"Dumpsters"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"@id":"http://www.site1.com","name":"Dumpsters"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"item":{"@id":"http://www.site1.com","name":"Dumpsters"}}]}}
```

You can see that only "http://www.site1.com" is being printed as the "@id"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Custom JavaScript Variable you have set up will only return the first value.

This is due to the return statement, as soon as the script evaluates this, it will return the current value, i.e index 0 and close the loop. Therefore it will only ever return the first index.

As you can't pass values into Custom JavasScript Variables, you will need to return a formatted object to use.

```
function() { 
var bcLink = document.getElementsByClassName("bcLink");
var data = [];
for (i=0; i<bcLink.length; i++) { 
// you will need to create/format the data suitable to your needs
data.push({ 'url' : bcLink[i].getAttribute("href") });
}
//return the data object to use elsewhere
return data;
}
```